# SQL Server: Convert comma separated values in a string into buckets based on the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a string "A,B,H1,J,P1,H3,L2" in a column. Need to segregate this into rows based on the number appended/not appended with each. So for the above example I should have 4 rows as output:

```
ABJ (no numbers associated with it)
HP (1 appended to it)
L (2 appended to it)
H (3 appended to it)
```

Comment: If at all possible, get the table design changed. A column should contain one piece of data - not several and (as here), definitely not several *types* of data (e.g. `H1` itself appears to be a composite of two distinct pieces of data)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of xml nodes:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = 'A,B,H1,J,P1,H3,L2',
        @xml xml

SELECT @xml = CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@string,',','</a><a>') +'</a>' as xml)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  t.v.value('.','nvarchar(10)') as v,
        CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(RIGHT(t.v.value('.','nvarchar(10)'),1) as int) IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE CAST(RIGHT(t.v.value('.','nvarchar(10)'),1) as int) END as g
FROM @xml.nodes('/a') as t(v)
)

SELECT REPLACE((
    SELECT v +''
    FROM cte c1
    WHERE c1.g= c.g
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),g,'') as [values]
FROM cte c
GROUP BY g
ORDER BY g
```

Output:

```
values
------
ABJ
HP
L
H
```